# In python multiprocessing, .get() always times out, even in code known to work

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

My multiprocessing code seems to work fine until I try to show some results using .get(), where it will hang forever unless I use .get(timeout=5) where I get an error saying it timed out. I am using code directly from the multiprocessing documentation page to ensure there are no errors.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

def f(q):
    q.put([42, None, 'hello'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    p = Process(target=f, args=(q,))
    p.start()
    print(q.get(timeout=5))    # prints "[42, None, 'hello']"
    p.join()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Empty                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-6adfdb672fe3> in <module>
      8     p = Process(target=f, args=(q,))
      9     p.start()
---> 10     print(q.get(timeout=5))    # prints "[42, None, 'hello']"
     11     p.join()

~\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py in get(self, block, timeout)
    103                     timeout = deadline - time.monotonic()
    104                     if not self._poll(timeout):
--> 105                         raise Empty
    106                 elif not self._poll():
    107                     raise Empty

Empty:
```

I really have no idea why .get() is taking forever, because almost every piece of example code I find for multiprocessing seems to use it just fine.

Comment: Your code works just fine for me.

Comment: I'm not sure what my issue is then. My computer is not necessarily a slow computer, but I've not run a single block of multiprocessing code that works for me, so I'm thinking there might be some change I can make to my system to allow it to work

Comment: Which Python version and where do you run this (IDE)?